# How to write a query that will return just the name at the start of an e-mail address? Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am very new to all this and I am trying to write a query so that when it returns an email address it will only return the part before the @ symbol. I have done some searches, but found nothing, perhaps I am asking the wrong questions?

So for example, instead of returning mike.smith@company.com, I want it to return mike.smith only?

Using Sqlite

Comment: declare @email nvarchar(255)= 'mike.smith@company.com'

select substring(@email,0,charindex('@', @email))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT substring_index(email,'@',1) as email FROM tableA;
```

It seeks the position of the `@`, and takes the number of characters up to but not including (that's the `- 1`) the `@` symbol.

Be careful with strings that don't have an `@` though; you'll end up an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply.

I am trying this,

SELECT
tickets.id, tickets.category, users.email, left (users.email, charindex('@', users.email) - 1), tickets.created_at, tickets.closed_at 

Yet I am getting a syntax error.

Again sorry, I am very new to SQL and have been dumped  a bit in the deep end.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: I should have added in my original question I am trying this in Sqlite. Still your help is still very useful and I think I am on the right track now. Will update as I figure it out. Again many thanks

Comment: I think that this will do have a try and tell me